# Bootstrap cards same max height and take largest height by content

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

I want to make Bootstrap cards the same height, there should be a max height, the height of the card should not exceed that limit. And the height of the other cards depends on the card which contains more content.

Here is a working sandbox [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-rgb-tb914h?file=/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

There are two alternative approaches to solving this issue.

1. You can specify `min-height` instead of `max-height` if the cards' data is static (the data won't come from an API) ( https://prnt.sc/mJMl3FSLTNM1 ).
2. If the data for the cards is dynamic (data from an API), you can use `height: 100%` for `.col.mb-3`. ( https://prnt.sc/FW4BqAmnkgJK )

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in following way.

1. Have a common CSS class on every card.
2. Set max-height on it.
3. Set the overflow property for text. So in case it becomes long it will overflow.

[image]